# Miniaturise all windows with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, ui

```
tell application "System Events"
    set mywindows to windows of (processes where background only is false)
    repeat with theItem in windows of (processes where background only is false)
        set miniaturized of theItem to true
    end repeat
end tell
```

I get

`error "System Events got an error: Can’t set miniaturized of UI element to any." number -10006 from miniaturized of UI element to any`

Comment: Don't you mean 'minimized'?

Comment: @benwiggy No, the  property is: `miniaturized`

Answer (score 1):

I answered [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288775/applescript-iterate-all-open-applications-process-and-execute-a-menu-command/49296629#49296629) over on Stack Overflow, around the time I was still working mostly in High Sierra.  Testing it today, it still works on Catalina.

Here's the salient part of that answer:

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to set the value of ¬
        attribute "AXMinimized" of every window of every process ¬
        to true
```

Unfortunately, it's not going to minimise them all simultaneously, which would be lovely.  It does them one-by-one, not necessary starting with the one that's right in front of you.  Therefore, if you have many windows open, it can appear at first that it's not doing anything, but in fact it's minimising windows obscured by the frontmost one), and they'll minimise in turn, which is fun to see the first time, but irksome every other time when you just want it done now.

Another point that @user3439894 kindly reminded me of is that *System Events* is only aware of objects that exist on the currently active desktop.  Therefore, this method won't be to minimise windows that are on other desktops/spaces are off-screen.

However, if you aren't specifically looking to minimise windows, but rather just get them out of sight, then you can elect to hide the processes instead:

```
tell application id "com.apple.systemevents" to ¬
        set visible of every process to false
```

The major annoyance here is that *Finder* remains visible, and will need to have an extra line of code after to get rid of its windows, which I suggest should be:

```
tell application id "com.apple.Finder" to set ¬
        miniaturized of every window to true
```

The benefits, however, are that all the windows across all desktops/screens will be gone, not just the ones on your current desktop; and this takes place very quickly, almost instantaneously (apart from *Finder*).  Activating the application by clicking on its dock icon for example, makes the process visible again; typically, this means that the application and all of its windows that were previously visible will re-appear en masse.  Whether that's a positive or negative will depend on your needs.

---

The reason your code doesn't work is because `miniaturised` is not a property of the `window` object belonging to the processes suite of *System Events'* AppleScript dictionary.  It ***is*** a property of `window` objects belonging to the *standard* suite of any **scriptable** application's AppleScript dictionary (including *SystemEvents*, although it doesn't have any windows of its own); despite sharing a common name, these two `window` class objects are distinct and unrelated objects in AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, hiding windows causes havoc with my system. (I can't get the windows back — they just flash. Alas!)

After some fiddling, I found a surprisingly elegant UI-hacky way to minimize everything instead:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with theProcess in processes
        if not background only of theProcess then
            try
                click (first button of (every window of (theProcess)) whose role description contains "minimize")
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

The script looks through every process, only considers those that are not backgrounded, and then *tries* to click the minimize button for each. You literally watch the system minimize each window for you, which could be either satisfying or aggravating. I'm trying to interpret it as satisfying.

Hope this helps!